# Why does this simple mysql query not use the index provided to it?

Tags: mysql

Below is my interaction with mysql. I have a simple query and an index on that column; but it only says using where instead of index. There are over 500 rows in the table.

```
[root@php-pos-db ~]# mysql
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4085957
Server version: 5.5.42-log Distributed by The IUS Community Project

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use phppoint_site;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show create table subscriptions;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| subscriptions | CREATE TABLE `subscriptions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address_1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address_2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `zip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `email` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `username` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subscr_id` varchar(19) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subscr_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `auth` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_installed` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cancel_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewed` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=897 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from subscriptions where username ='me';
+-----+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-----+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| id  | company | name         | country | address_1 | address_2 | city | state | zip | email              | phone | username | password | subscr_id | subscr_status | quantity | auth | is_installed | cancel_date | viewed |
+-----+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-----+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------+--------------+-------------+--------+
| 418 |         | Chris Muench |         |           |           |      |       |     | me@chrismuench.com |       | me       |          |           | payment       |        1 |      |            1 | NULL        |      0 |
+-----+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------+------+-------+-----+--------------------+-------+----------+----------+-----------+---------------+----------+------+--------------+-------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from subscriptions where username ='me';
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | subscriptions | ref  | username      | username | 92      | const |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: It used the index. Using where is under extra. Had it not used the index, you'd have full table scan and row column would have number of all rows listed there.

Comment: I thought it would say "Using index"